# Как сделать extend нескольких параметров?

Tags: android

Хочу подключить к классу несколько параметров сразу. Было так:

```
public class MessageCenter extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener
```

а я еще хочу добавить сюда `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`. Можно ли вообще подключить сюда как-то этот адаптер.

### UPDATE

Мой адаптер:

```
public class PagerAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {
    private int mNoOfTabs;

    public PagerAdapter(FragmentManager fm,int NumberOfTabs) {
        super(fm);
        this.mNoOfTabs = NumberOfTabs;
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        switch (position)
        {
            case 0:
                return new Received();
            case 1:
                return new Sent();
                default:
            return new Received();
        }

    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mNoOfTabs;
    }
}
```

мой класс в который я хочу внедрить этот адаптер:

```
public class MessageCenter extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

    PagerAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_message_center);
        Toolbar toolbar = findViewById(R.id.toolbar);
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar);

        FloatingActionButton fab = findViewById(R.id.fab);
        fab.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Intent intent2 = new Intent(MessageCenter.this, WriteResponseMess.class);
                startActivity(intent2);
            }
        });

        mAdapter = new PagerAdapter(getFragmentManager()) {
            @Override
            public int getCount() {
                return 0;
            }

            @Override
            public boolean isViewFromObject(@NonNull View view, @NonNull Object o) {
                return false;
            }
        };
        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);

        DrawerLayout drawer = findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(
                this, drawer, toolbar, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
        drawer.addDrawerListener(toggle);
        toggle.syncState();

        NavigationView navigationView = findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
        navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```

строка `getFragmentManager` подсвечена красным, ничего не помогает что-бы ее сделать нормального цвета.

Comment: НЕТ!!! В Java запрещено множественное наследование!!!

Comment: и что никак фрагменты не подключить?

Comment: А что мешает создать отдельно реализацию данного Адаптера? Фрагменты можно подключить. Для этого используйте fragment manager. Рекомндую для начала прочитать http://developer.alexanderklimov.ru/android/theory/fragments.php

Comment: просто мне нужно в моем меню при нажатии на определенный элемент переходить на определенный фрагмент, а для этого я использую функцию `public Fragment getItem(int position)`, либо сделать по-другому - при нажатии на элемент меню переходить просто на другое активити, но это слишком крупное телодвижение, так же я хочу сделать один из элементов списка меню задавался по-умолчанию и при открытии активити с меню что-бы уже открывалась определенная вкладка

Comment: Нещадно минусую тех кто путает язык со средой разработки

Comment: @Barmaley при чем здесь это? вы про теги вопроса?

Comment: Да, конечно. Я вот лично уже устал постоянно редактировать метки - должно же быть понимание, что Android и Android Studio отличаются таки друг от друга...

Comment: Да я понял свою ошибку, удалил вопрос из метки `android-studio`. После нескольких месяцев работы в в этой IDE начинаешь замечать отличия от `Android`))

Comment: Вместо getFragmentManager() вам нужно использовать getSupportFragmentManager(), т.к. вы используете AppCompatActivity

Comment: *После нескольких месяцев работы в этой IDE начинаешь замечать отличия от Android* - вы начинаете замечть разницу между молотком и вбитым с его помощью гвоздем только через месяц заколачивания этих гвоздей ? Студия - инструмент разработки, программа-редактор текста (кода) и отладки. Android - фреймворк, операционная система, выполняющая готовые программы. Тег `android-studio` ставится только к вопросам, связанным с проблемами в самой IDE, а не с кодом, который вы в ней пишите

Comment: Попробуйте через `Generics`.

Answer (score 1):

`Activity` (в вашем случае `MessageCenter`) и не должна наследоваться от адаптера (`FragmentStatePagerAdapter`), вы можете использовать композицию вместо наследования (в Java множественное наследование реализаций (классов) запрещено).

Т.е. Вы можете создать отдельный класс, наследующийся от `FragmentStatePagerAdapter`:

```
public static class MyAdapter extends FragmentStatePagerAdapter {...}
```

а затем в использовать его в `MessageCenter`, например, следующим образом:

```
public class MessageCenter extends AppCompatActivity implements NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {
    MyAdapter mAdapter;
    ViewPager mPager;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.fragment_pager);

        mAdapter = new MyAdapter(getFragmentManager());
        mPager = (ViewPager)findViewById(R.id.pager);
        mPager.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        ...
    }
```

А если проблема в

> строка getFragmentManager подсвечена красным, ничего не помогает
>   что-бы ее сделать нормального цвета.

то вместо `getFragmentManager()` Вам нужно использовать `getSupportFragmentManager()`.

Comment: не получается так как вы советуете, сейчас дополню вопрос адаптером и тем что у меня на данный момент получается.

Comment: MessageCenter ??? AppCompatActivity

Comment: да AppCompatActivity

Comment: @Ksenia, скажите пожалуйста, нужен ли вообще адаптер, потому-что методы которые там я использовал никак не используются при выборе пунктов меню?

Comment: @AndrewGoroshko, нужен. Методы, которые вы там определяете - getItem(), getCount() - Вы и не должны вызывать, их вызывает система, это метода обратного вызова.

Comment: то есть если я вас правильно понял, адаптер не обязательно объявлять в классе меню? просто у меня никак не получается получить желаемый результат((

Comment: у меня постоянно выводит содержимое только одного фрагмента, а второй пишет что `No adapter attached; skipping layout`. Может эта ошибка относится к проблеме того что показывает только один фрагмент?